# cookie issue cookie not functioning properly

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am having serious cookie issues. if I login without using remember me, everything is fine.

If I check remember me, it lets me login but if I close the browser and open it back up it wont auto login it just says page cannot be displayed like its a corrupt cookie.

the only way to make it work again is to delete the cookie

Here is my set function:

```
if ($remember == "on") {                

             setcookie('email', $email, time() + 86400);

            }
```

Here is my logout function:

```
session_destroy();

if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['email']);

    setcookie('email', '', time() - 86400);
}

redirect("index.php");
```

Also, when I look at the cookie file in explorer browser, it looks like this:

```
email
me%40mymail.net
localhost/mysite/account/
17408
78850176
30494094
3665530565
30493892
```

So what happens is, I have to delete the cookie to show the login page again.

Comment: I had to read your top paragraph 6 times .. Please use punctuation so that people can just get in and help without having to "decipher" your meaning :-)

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable, but, it's still a but unclear what the actual problem is. You reference "remember me" functionality, but don't include any of that code. And you don't actually *ask a question*. Please provide additional context so we can understand what it is you need help with.

Comment: I edited it some more I don't know how much more clear I can make it :-(

Comment: unset() does **not** remove a cookie

Comment: @ John ok unset() don't delete a cookie. deleting it is not the issue my issue is if I check remember me login then close the browser then open the browser again I should be able to go to the account area.. how ever it does not allow me to it just says page cannot be displayed then I have to manually remove it. to get the site to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured out the issue... for some reason it had to do with the directories

to set the cookie I changed this

```
if ($remember == "on") {                

             setcookie('email', $email, time() + 86400);

            }
```

to this

```
if ($remember == "on") {                

             setcookie("email", $email, time() + 86400,'/');
            }
```

and I changed this

```
session_destroy();

if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['email']);

    setcookie('email', '', time() - 86400);
}

redirect("index.php");
```

to this

```
session_destroy();

if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])){

    unset($_COOKIE['email']);

    setcookie("email", '', time() + 86400,'/');

}

redirect("index.php");
```